# Uninstalling demo/trial of Visual Studio 2008 Team System

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-installer

I wish to uninstall the trail copy of VS 2008 Team System, as the trial is coming to its end.  I had VS 2008 Professional Edition installed on the machine to start with and it still shows up in Add/Remove Problems.

I am hoping that when I uninstall VS 2008 Team System I will be left with a working VS 2008 Professional Edition.

When I try to uninstall VS 2008 Team System, I very quickly get an error dialog that says:

> A problem has been encountered while
>   loading the setup components.
>   Canceling setup.

**Help!**

**Progress or lack there of so fare**

I have done dir %temp%*.log in a command prompt and can see any log files that are recent

I am going to read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer#Diagnostic_logging to see if I can get any logging

Aaron Stebner's WebLog has a post on [where VS put's is log files](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2007/07/31/4156781.aspx), he also has a [post on were some other products put there log files](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2008/02/27/7927123.aspx)
gives some info about where VS setup puts it's logs etc

Aaron Ruckman provided me with the solution after I sent him the log files.

Comment: so what was the solution?

Comment: @theninjagreg, looking at old emails, installing patch KB959417 fixed the problem, however I don't expect it would work for someone 3 years later as it is very unlickly a system will be setup the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HI, your issue could be related to the one posted on http://blogs.msdn.com/heaths/archive/2008/10/06/adding-features-to-visual-studio-2008-may-fail-to-load-setup-components.aspx

Essentially what has happened is that you have Pro Trial still installed and it is expiring.  so what you need to do is go to the "Add/Remove Programs" and uninstall the Microsoft Visual Studio Pro 2008 Trial.  You shouldn't have to touch your Microsoft Visual Studio Team Suite Edition.

If this doesn't work then feel free to email me aaronru(a)microsoft.com.  When you do so please use the tool described here http://blogs.msdn.com/heaths/archive/2008/05/09/visual-studio-and-net-log-collection-utility.aspx to collect your logs and upload them somewhere and then send me a link to them.

thanks!

Aaron Ruckman

Program Mananager

Visual Studio

Microsoft Corp.

Comment: Thanks; the first blog post did not help, as I am running Setup from Add/Remove programs.  I have emailed you the log files as requested so you can see if you can spot the problem.

Comment: me too. I've sent the logs, hopefully we'll get an update on progress, or a fix. cheers.

Comment: "Program Mananager" lol, let's hope he changed his signature.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the blog http://blogs.msdn.com/heaths/archive/2008/10/06/adding-features-to-visual-studio-2008-may-fail-to-load-setup-components.aspx, I tried to use the workaround but it seems the installer for that incorrectly determines the available disk space (C drive on my pc had 5 GB of free space but installer calculated it as 5MB and did not continue the installation!)

So i used the HOTFOX http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB959417/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2201 and it worked.

Thanks for the info.
Sameer

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, unfortunately I do not believe I ever found a solution that did not require reinstalling VS 2008 Professional Edition.

Basically I used the following tool:

[AutoUninstallTool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb968856.aspx)

And then manually removed anything from Add/Remove Programs related to Visual Studio that was left.

Note that there was a stackoverflow question on the first page when I googled the error report:
[Visual Studio setup problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114332/visual-studio-setup-problem-a-problem-has-been-encountered-while-loading-the-s)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed ti by running the set up file in the %Program Files%\C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Microsoft Visual Studio Team System 2008 Team Suite - ENU\ folder.

I was able to remove the install.