# Web Application project type not available in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm running Visual Studio 2008 Professional, but I can't seem to open a project that has project types:

```
{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};
{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}
```

The first type (349c...) is the Web Application project type. The second type is the C# project type.

I'm getting the error message "The project type is not supported by this installation." I'm assuming it doesn't recognize the Web Application project type.

In Visual Studio 2005, it was necessary to install an add-on to enable the Web Application project type. For Visual Studio 2008, the documentation indicates that the Web Application project type is incorporated into the system proper (i.e. an add-on is not necessary).

Why am I still getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the Web Application project type is part of the Visual Web Developer installation option.

When I add that to the installation, I'm able to open Web Application projects.

Comment: If, like me, you run into problems adding Visual Web Application to your instance of VS2008, check out these solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114332/visual-studio-setup-problem-a-problem-has-been-encountered-while-loading-the