# reinstall/uninstall/change windows phone 7.1 sdk

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sdk, windows-phone-7.1

I cant Uninstall/change windows phone 7.1 sdk. It has allready installed in my system. but i cant see phone app. in VS10 (ultimate 64X). if I want to reinstall/uninstall/change occuring this error:

"A problem has been encountered while loading the setup components. Canceling setup."

thanks.

Comment: Did you try to uninstall it from VS 2010 CD ? or from Control Panel ?

Comment: See this StackOverflow post : [Visual Studio setup problem - 'A problem has been encountered while loading the setup components. Canceling setup.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114332/visual-studio-setup-problem-a-problem-has-been-encountered-while-loading-the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall the "Hotfix for Windows Phone 7.1 Async CTP" in installed updates in Control Panel.
Reboot your computer.
And I reinstalled the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

I Uninstalled the "Hotfix for Windows Phone 7.1 Async CTP" in installed updates in control panel.

And I reinstalled the SDK again. This site do hint me for the correct solution : http://codexl.blogspot.com/2009/07/visual-studio-2008-setup-problem-has_29.html

thanks for comments.